# inheriting from WebPart with custom ToolPart

Tags: web-part, toolpart

There is a custom web part (let's call it WebPartA) and custom Tool Part for it. We need to inherit from this web part and extend it with two integer properties (WebPartB). And add default controls for editing these properties (like text boxes).

Is there a way to do this withot modifying/extending custom tool part?

Right now custom tool part generates controls only for WebPartA's properties. We've added two properties to the WebPartB and marked them with attributes:

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
 Category("Slider Settings"),
 Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
 WebPartStorage(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.Storage.Shared),
 DefaultValue(1000),
 WebDisplayName("SomeProperty"),
 WebDescription("Please enter SomeProperty")]
public Int32 SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

But these properties doesn't appear on the web part editor.